# How to concat string values in array list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

I need to print all arraylist values at a time using concat.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("hi");
lst.add("hello");
Iterator<String> itr = lst.iterator();
String result = null;

while(itr.hasNext()) {
   Object element = itr.next();
   result = element + " ";
}

System.out.println(result);
```

The expected result should be `hi hello`.

The current output however is `hello` (there is also a *whitespace* at the end).

Comment: Please post the error messages that you are receiving. Also post a presentable version of what is being entered and what the output needs to look like. In this state the question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Look at the javadoc for `String` and see if there are any methods that would make this easier for you.

Comment: It currently just outputs `hello[whitespace]`, for the record.

Comment: I think if you take a good look at what you're assigning into `result` each time in the loop, you will see why you're getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please prefer the `List` interface to the `ArrayList` concrete type. Assuming you are using Java 8+, you might use a `Stream` and `Collectors.joining` (and `Arrays.asList`) like

```
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("hi", "hello");
String r = lst.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(r);
```

Which outputs

```
hi hello
```

As requested.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is pretty small. In each iteration you assign a value to the `result` variable. However instead of **updating** your existing content you just erase it and enter a new value.

You do `result = element + " "`. But it should be something like `result = result + element + " "` or the same in short:

```
result += element + " ";
```

This way the first iteration will save `hi` in it and after that `hello` gets **appended** resulting in `hi hello` (instead of overriding the content of the first iteration).

Note that it now also has the whitespace at the end. You could delete it with `result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1)`. Or not add it in the last iteration, but then you need to count the iterations.

---

Please note that Java has a class [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) that does exactly what you want, joining some elements together and also using a delimiter like *whitespace*. You use it like this:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object element = itr.next();
    sj.add(element);
}
String result = sj.toString();
```

Also note that since **Java 8** there is an even shorter version of it:

```
String result = String.join(" ", list);
```